# Why I got this error when setting the spark context?

Tags: java, apache-spark, gradle

I am trying to setup the spark context as below.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        SparkConf sparkConf = conf.setAppName("test");

    }
}
```

However, the intelliJ throw the error indicating that I cannot `access the scala.Clonable` in the line `SparkConf sparkConf = conf.setAppName("test");`.

I correctly made the gradle document so that all the libraries that I need have been downloaded to my repository as below.

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    compile "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.6.1"
}
```

I look forward to your reply.

Thanks.

Comment: which version of scala are you using ?  It seems to me that you are using a version of scala different that the 2.10

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you are using the wrong version of scala.

Try to explicitly add the scala library to the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.5'
}
```

this should trigger the use of the correct scala compiler